# Regular Expressions Query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g

I have to read a string column and load a value in a number column based on the string:

'S12345' - 12345 (Remove 1st alphabet and load the remaining numbers)

'12345' - 12345 (Load the number directly)

'12345T' - NULL (Load NULL if the last character is alphabet)

'1A2B3C45' or 'SQ12345' - NULL (Load NULL if there are more than 1 alphabets in the string)

I am trying to devise a query using CASE and REGEXP_LIKE, with no luck. Can someone please help me with the query for the specific requirement. Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Please show what you tried. We're not here to do your work for you, but we'll help you fix your non-working code.

Comment: What would `1A2` return (AKA a number with only 1 letter in the string, but not at the beginning)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
^[A-Za-z]?(\d+)$
```

**[Here](https://regex101.com/r/pA0eK3/2)** is an example with some testdata, you can add your own lines of data to test it.

Comment: Note: `[A-z] != [A-Za-z]`

Comment: Just curious, but if your regexp interpreter supports \d it also supports \w instead of [A-Za-z], so why not `^[\w]?(\d+)$` ?

Comment: Because `\w` also contains `0-9`. At whole numberstrings like `12345` it only captures `2345` in the capturegroup because the first character is optional but matches with `\w` but not with `[A-Za-z]`.